# curl change path of download to dynamically

Tags: windows, curl

I want to make a batch so it can download files to a desktop folder for anyone who clicks on it

this is the static code

```
curl --output C:\Users\admin\Desktop\stuff/file.zip --url https://wordpress.org/latest.zip
```

I want to make it dynamic - the path changing depend on the pc

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

#### I want to make it dynamic - the path changing depend on the pc

I presume by "dynamic" you want the path to refer to the user running the batch file?

In that case replace `C:\Users\admin` with the System environment variable `%USERPROFILE%`.

```
curl --output %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\stuff\file.zip --url https://wordpress.org/latest.zip
```

You need to make sure the directory `Desktop\stuff` exists otherwise create it.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Windows Environment Variables - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)